# Finding the closest centroids in a k means clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, octave, k-means

With

```
X = [1.8421 4.6076;
     5.6586 4.8;
     6.3526 3.2909;
     2.904  4.6122;
     3.232  4.9399;
     1.2479 4.9327]
```

And

```
centroids = [3  3;
             6  2;
             8  5]
```

I'm trying to find the nearest centroid to each point in x.
I'm coding in Octave and here's my code

```
K = size(centroids, 1);
idx = zeros(size(X,1), 1);   %idx is the vector storing the index of the closest centroid
for e = 1: size(X,1)
    difference(1, :) = X(e,:) - centroids(1,:);
    min_distance = sum(difference(1,:).^2);
    for j = 2:K
        difference(j, :) = X(e,:) - centroids(j,:);
        distance = sum(difference.^2);
        if distance<min_distance
            min_distance = distance;
            idx(e) = centroids(j);
        endif
    endfor
endfor
```

The code works, but I only get

```
idx = 0 0 0
```

for the first three entries of x

Comment: Same issues: `x` and `X` are not the same variable. You are not defining the size of `difference`. `idx` should be a colum vector 6x1 , how became a matrix 3x2 ? Check indexes on both sides of `idx(e) = centroids(j)` ; may be your intention was  `idx(e) = j` and you forgot to set idx(e)=1 on the outer loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be consistent in the size of your operand when you are calculating
the distance and properly set idx:

```
K = size(centroids, 1);
difference=zeros(size(centroids));
idx = zeros(size(X,1), 1);   %idx is the vector storing the index of the closest centroid
for e = 1: size(X,1)
    difference(1, :) = X(e,:) - centroids(1,:);
    min_distance = sum(difference(1,:).^2);
    idx(e)=1;
    for j = 2:K
        difference(j, :) = X(e,:) - centroids(j,:);
        distance = sum(difference(j,:).^2);
        if (distance<min_distance)
            min_distance = distance;
            idx(e) = j;
        endif
    endfor
endfor
idx
```

with this change the output is:

```
idx =

   1
   3
   2
   1
   1
   1
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne!


I figured out the error just a few minutes before your answer, and came here to delete my question. Thanks a lot for your answer.  <3

Answer (score 0):

You may find the min function useful, when using Octave ;)

```
[minimum_values, minimum_index] = min(k);
```

You would use the minimum_index value for idx, for example:

```
idx(i) = minimum_index;
```

You could therefore reduce this further to:

```
[minimum_values, idx(i)] = min(k);
```